# Calling Single Apex Class From Two Different Apex Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger

Assuming I have two apex classes wherein `Class1` handles the simultaneous insertion of parent `Parent__c` and child `Child__c` records, and wherein `Class2` handles computations.

Meanwhile, let's also assume that I have two apex triggers:

**Trigger1 for** `Parent__c` **object**:  (for every `Parent__c` record inserted, there will be `Parent2__c` record inserted)

**Trigger2 for** `Child__c` **object**: (for every `Child__c` records inserted, there will be `Child2__c` records inserted)

Is it possible to call `Class2` apex class from these two triggers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, just like any OOP language, classes do not care where they are executed from. If your class 2 methods are static, in your triggers you would simply call

```
Class2.method();
```

Keep in mind that each trigger.new will be different SObject types so your Class2 methods will need to be written with that in mind. Either being generic and take List< SObject > or have different methods for Parents and Child.

Without more detail I can't provide much more other then a yes, you can call it from two triggers.